# Play Framework Anorm & DB Not Resolved

Tags: mysql, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, anorm

I'm using the Play Framework 2.2.3 for my first time and I'm having a lot of trouble importing anorm._ and api.db.DB so I can set up my SQL databases.

My set-up is this:

MainController.scala

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db.DB
import anorm._

object MainController extends Controller {...}
```

application.conf

```
# db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:mysql:/usr/local/path/to/database"
```

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"
```

My first question is whether or not I'm setting up MySQL database connection correctly. The other thing is that when I try to find the import with my IntelliJ, it finds it great. But when I compile in my browser, I get a compilation error: object db is not a member of package play.api. Any tips?

I downloaded both Play 2.2.2 and 2.2.3, and with both I had this problem so version problems are ruled out. I installed from the website, I unzipped the file into my Home folder, and used

```
play new app
cd app/
play
idea with-sources=yes
```

for my installation. I honestly just have no idea what's going on.

Comment: All of these questions are addressed in the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDatabase

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and it's resolved by adding: `"com.typesafe.play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.2.3"`, in my `build.scala` file.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this to your dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-jdbc_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```