# Anorm and JDBC dependencies not found in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, anorm

I am running my application with Play Framework(version: 2.2.3), it's giving compilation errors like: not found value anorm and not found value jdbc, I am not sure whether it has connected with my database set up or not ? I have checked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073280/play-framework-anorm-db-not-reseolved), but still no use. Please help me that where I am doing wrong ?.

I have done the following:

build.scala:

```
import sbt._
object AppBuild extends Build {
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc,
    "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
    "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41",
     "com.typesafe.play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.2.3"
    )
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // we can add our own project settings     
  )
}
```

app.scala:

package models

```
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._ 
import play.api.db.DB 
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

case class Test(id: Pk[Long], content: String)

object Test {

  def create(test: Test): Unit = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("insert into test(content) values ({content})").on(
        'content -> test.content
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
 }
```

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3")
```

app.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abcdatabase"
```

Comment: You have dependencies defined several times with different version. Not good. `jdbc` and `anorm` are app dependdncies: not to be defined in `plugins.sbt`. With Play 2.2 the default `anorm` is Anorm 2.2, but then you add another dependency to Anorm 2.4. Then check whether you see error while the dependencies are resolved for  compile, possibly after having removed or renamed you `~/.ivy`. You can also test using the Scala console (`play console` or `sbt console` from the project dir), trying the `import anotm._`

Comment: Methinks `"com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0"` is just be for play 2.4, not for 2.2. You can take it out for 2.2.

Comment: @cchantep, thanks for your replies, I have got to know that from you, I need not to add anorm dependency for Play 2.2.2, since it comes by default, so I have modified my question description(changed/removed anorm-2.4.0 dependency from build.scala and removed those two dependencies from plugins.sbt, this time I am getting error like: not found jdbc (in build.scala) ? I am not sure why I am getting this compilation error ?

Comment: @wwkudu, thanks for your replies, I have got to know that from you, I need not to add anorm dependency for Play 2.2.2, since it comes by default, so I have modified my question description(changed/removed anorm-2.4.0 dependency from build.scala and removed those two dependencies from plugins.sbt, this time I am getting error like: not found jdbc (in build.scala) ? I am not sure why I am getting this compilation error ?

Comment: Being provided doesn't mean you don't have to declare the dependency to `anorm` (just mean you have the Anorm version corresponding to your Play version without having to resolve it from an online repository). You mention Play 2.2.2, but your plugin is 2.2.1. I suggest you download a fresh Play dist to do your tests.

Comment: If I remove jdbc dependency, I am getting compilation error like in app.scala: DB.withConnection { implicit connection => ... not found value DB. and object db is not a member of package play.api, added it in question description

Comment: @cchantep, If I add: "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0", I am not seeing any error on console regarding anorm dependency.

Comment: Once not using Play dependent module (such as Anorm Iteratee), Anorm can used as plain/standalone dependency, in any version up to 2.5.0

Comment: I have used: "com.typesafe.play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.2.3" , still I am getting jdbc not found error. I have changed to 2.2.3 Play and sbt.

Comment: It's resolved after adding the statement: "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.10" % "2.2.0-RC1" in build.scala, so I am not getting any dependency issues, resolved all and then enters into my application. Hopefully, it helps to anyone. Thanks all !!